# In pandas is there a way to compute a subsection of a expanding window; without calculating the entire array and "tail-ing" the result

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compute the expanding window of just the last few elements in a group...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1,1], 'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2,1,2]})

df.groupby("A")["B"].expanding().quantile(0.5)
```

this gives:

```
 1  0    NaN    
    2    1.0    
    4    1.5    
    6    1.0    
 2  1    NaN
    3    1.0
    5    1.5
    7    1.0
```

**I only really want the last two rows for each group though.** the result should be:

```
 1  4    1.5    
    6    1.0    
 2  5    1.5
    7    1.0
```

I can easily calculate it all and then just get the sections I want. but this is very slow if my dataframe is 1000s of elements long and I dont want to roll across the whole window... just the last two "rolls"

EDIT: I have ammended the title; A lot of people are correctly answering part of the question, but ignoring what is IMO the important part (I should have been more clear) 
The issue here is the time it takes. I could just "tail" the answer to get the last two; but then it involves calculating the first two "expanding windows" and then throwing away those results. If my dataframe was instead 1000s of rows long and I just needed the answer for the last few entries, much of this calculation would be wasting time. This is the main problem I have. 
As I stated:
"I can easily calculate it all and then just get the sections I want" => through using tail. 
Sorry for the confusion.
Also potentially using tail **doesnt** involve calculating the lot, but it still seems like it does from the timings that I have done... maybe this is not correct, it is an assumption I have made.

EDIT2: The other Option I have tried was using the min_windows in rolling to force it to not calculate the initial sections of the group, but this has many pitfalls such as: -if the array includes NaNs this doesnt work, -if the groupbys are not the same length.

EDIT3:
As a simpler problem and reasoning: Its a limitation of the expanding/or rolling window I think... say we had an array [1,2,3,4,5] the expanding windows are  [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5], and if we run the max over that we get: 1,2,3,4,5 (the max of each array). But if I just want the max of the last two expanding windows. I just need max[1,2,3,4] = 4 and max[1,2,3,4,5]. Intuitively I don't need to calculate max of the first 3 expanding window results to get the last two. But Pandas Implementation might be that it calculates max[1,2,3,4] as max[max[1,2,3],max[4]] = 4 in which case the calculation of the entire window is necessary... this might be the same for the quantile example. There might be an alternate way to do this however without using expanding... not sure... this is what I cant work out.

Comment: You said you want rolling but you used expanding.  Those are completely different things and only makes your question confusing.  It looks like one of the deleted answers gave you exactly what you asked for.  If it wasn't what you needed then it must be that you need to better explain what it is you want.

Comment: I didn't delete the answer. I think it was getting close to what I was after. I probably should adjust the title to expanding, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using tail: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].rolling(4, min_periods=1).quantile(0.5).reset_index(level=0).groupby('A').tail(2)
Out[410]:
   A    B
4  1  1.5
6  1  1.0
5  2  1.5
7  2  1.0
```

rolling and expanding are similar

How about this (edited 06/12/2018):

```
def last_two_quantile(row, q):
    return pd.Series([row.iloc[:-1].quantile(q), row.quantile(q)])

df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(last_two_quantile, 0.5)
Out[126]:
A
1  0    1.5
   1    1.0
2  0    1.5
   1    1.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

If this (or something like it) doesn't do what you desire I think you should provide a real example of your use case.

Comment: Hi cosmic_inquiry,  thanks for the answer, but I guess I really want to avoid using tail as I think it still computes the entire thing then throws away all the other results. I have updated my question to make it more clear. Sorry.

Comment: How can you calculate the quantile of distribution, if you only have knowledge of part of it? As this calculation demonstrates:
```In [21]: df.groupby('A').tail(2).groupby('A')['B'].expanding().quantile(0.5)

Out[21]:

A
1  4    2.0
   6    1.5
2  5    2.0
   7    1.5```
If you only consider part of the distribution, the quantile will be different...

Comment: If you are trying to tell pandas "consider the entire distribution, but only do the quantile calculation for the last few numbers" I don't know of a way to do that. Perhaps that's what you're after

Comment: Yeah. I don't think there is a way to do it with the standard expanding/quantile functions. But I was hoping some pandas wizard would tell me I am being foolish and just need to do "x". I added Edit3 which explains how Im not really ignoring any of the distribution in the result... just dont compute the results for the initial expanding window sections of the distribution.

Comment: Yup this is exactly what I was after. Not sure on speed but it will definitely achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
df[-4:].groupby("A")["B"].expanding().quantile(0.5)

A   
1  4    2.0
   6    1.5
2  5    2.0
   7    1.5
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Hope can help you.

Solution1:

```
newdf = df.groupby("A")["B"].expanding().quantile(0.5).reset_index()
for i in range(newdf["A"].max()+1):
    print(newdf[newdf["A"]==i][-2:],'\n')
```

Solution2:

```
newdf2 = df.groupby("A")["B"].expanding().quantile(0.5)
for i in range(newdf2.index.get_level_values("A").max()+1):
    print(newdf[newdf["A"]==i][-2:],'\n')
```

Solution3:

```
for i in range(df.groupby("A")["B"].expanding().quantile(0.5).index.get_level_values("A").max()+1):
    print(newdf[newdf["A"]==i][-2:],'\n')
```

output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, level_1, B]
Index: [] 

   A  level_1    B
2  1        4  1.5
3  1        6  1.0 

   A  level_1    B
6  2        5  1.5
7  2        7  1.0
```

new solution:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns={"A", "B"})
for i in range(len(df["A"].unique())):
    newdf = newdf.append(pd.DataFrame(df[df["A"]==i+1][:-2].sum()).T)
newdf["A"] = newdf["A"]/2
for i in range(len(df["A"].unique())):
    newdf = newdf.append(df[df["A"]==df["A"].unique()[i]][-2:])
#newdf = newdf.reset_index(drop=True)
newdf["A"] = newdf["A"].astype(int)
for i in range(newdf["A"].max()+1):
    print(newdf[newdf["A"]==i].groupby("A")["B"].expanding().quantile(0.5)[-2:])
```

output:

```
Series([], Name: B, dtype: float64)
A   
1  4    1.5
   6    1.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
A   
2  5    1.5
   7    1.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: not quite: as it gives the incorrect answers as the resulting quantiles do not use the NAN or first 1 in their quantile calculations

Comment: sorry, I don't notice that, I change the answer here!

`newdf = df.groupby("A")["B"].expanding().quantile(0.5).reset_index()
for i in range(newdf["A"].max()+1):
    print(newdf[newdf["A"]==i][-2:],'\n')`

Comment: That still calculates all of the rolling quantiles just to get the last two. it would be okay here, but if the input df is 1000s of elements long its a lot of wasted computation. I think the best way might be to use transform or apply. but I cant work it out :s,

Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: I add a new solution, but I think it's not the smart code, and not also sure it could be faster. I just started learn python, hope can help you.

Comment: Thank you Joy, I tried the last piece, and from what I could tell, it breaks down the groups and does each group individually: then does the quantile over the entire set and selects the last two results.
It gets the right answer, but I believe doesn't address the idea of not calculating the entire expanding windows.